# how to make the loop more effective in java netbeans

Tags: java, oop, netbeans

I am new to java and I am implementing a book system project in java. I have created a loop that will validate customer age if they are < 18 will need parent provision to proceed if> 18 the customer can proceed to book class.

The loop ends when a customer has entered an age that is < 18, which is what I want the function to do. But when the age is greater than 18 the warning of the age provision shows when the age is greater than 18.

I have included an else statement but the code still continued to show in the terminal.  **System.out.println("You can not proceed without parent supervision as you are under the age of 18 !");**   even though the age is > than 18.

Please just let me know what needs to be tweaked within the loop so it is more effective

// VALIDATE CUSTOMER AGE  / AGE RESTRICTION

```
while (true) {

    System.out.println("Pleaste enter your age");
    customerAge = sc.nextInt();

    if (customerAge < 18) {

    }

    System.out.println("You can not proceed without parent supervision as you are under the age of 18 !");

    if (customerAge > 17) {
        break;

    }
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message should be inside the if block:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Pleaste enter your age");
    customerAge = sc.nextInt();
    if (customerAge < 18) {
        System.out.println("You can not proceed without parent supervision as you are under the age of 18 !");
        continue;
    }    
    break;
}
```

It is not clear as why you want the loop to stop if the age is < 18. 
If the age is >= 18 what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your home work but this how you should be checking:

```
with in while
    if (customerAge < 18) {
         // print the warning message
         break from for loop
    } 
    //do your stuff this mean customer is an adult.
```

Your print statement in not guarded by a test condition and hence you see it's been printed for adult customer as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need in your while loop to validate that,

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Pleaste enter your age");
    customerAge = sc.nextInt();

    if (customerAge < 18) {
        System.out.println("You can not proceed without parent supervision as you are under the age of 18 !");
        break;
    }
}
```